# AC dimming with STM32 timers

Tags: stm32, pwm, timer, dimming

I'm using an STM32 for AC dimming, for which I use a GPIO output (or timer channel out) to drive a triac, whenever I get a zero crossing detection (rising edge). Is there a way to solve this only using timers architecture and without firmware overhead?i.e not using interrupt handlers.

- Toff -> configurable.
- Tonn -> remains the same.

[image]

Comment: "*I output PWM signal to triac ...*" You can't use PWM on a triac. Once a triac turns on it remains on until the next zero-cross. I think you need to edit your question to explain it better.

Comment: Yes, after each zero crossing I wait for Toff time and the triac is turned on later triac is switched off at zerocross.

Comment: Mains frequency is low (100 or 120 zero-crosses per second). Why not have your code check the zero-cross in the main program loop?

Comment: It shouldnt be problem , just wanted to know if the stm32 timer architecture is self-sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a timer (A) in single shot triggered from an external pin.
This external pin is your zero crossing detector.

You also may need a timer (B) to measure the frequency.

Software still needs to calculate the duty cycle percentage based on the frequency. And set timer A reload to the measured value in timer B.

However, you could use a DMA operation triggered by timer A to copy the capture time of B to the reload register of A. But, you're calculating with those numbers anyway.

---

Having an ISR called at 50Hz isn't a problem when it doesn't take a lot of time to process it.

Comment: It shouldnt be problem , just wanted to know if the stm32 timer architecture is self-sufficient

Comment: STM32 arch can do it. Use so-called PWM combined mode and then you can set *programmable delay* and *programmable on-time* with 2x CC channels.